# Blender 2.93 and 3.0 Sky Texture and Environment Texture

Tags: texturing

Trying to understand why in 2.93 Sky Texture or Environment Texture does not work at all.
But in 3.0 all is well?

Comment: found the issue. Viewport shading turned off

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.